# Question about the proof for "every field is a euclidean domain."

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

$\color{black}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Definition:}$  An integral domain $R$ is a Euclidean domain if there is a function $\delta$ from the nonzero elements of $R$ to the nonnegative integers with these properties;

$(i)$  If $a$ and $b$ are nonzero elements of $R,$ then $\delta(a)\leq \delta(ab).$

$(ii)$  If $a,b\in R$ and $b\neq 0_R,$ then there exist $q,r\in R$ such that $a=bq+r$ and either $r=0_R$ or $\delta(r) < \delta(b).$

$\textbf{Exercise 14:}$  Let $R$ be a field.  Prove that $R$ is a Euclidean domain with the function $\delta$ given by $\delta(a)=0$ for each nonzero $a\in R.$

$\textbf{Exercise 29:}$  Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain.  If the function $\delta$ is a constant function, prove that $R$ is a field.

$\color{black}{Questions:}$

I have a question about exercise 14 above.  I have seen in some proof of exercise 14 that the $\delta(a)=1$ instead of $\delta(a)=0$. I am just wondering if it matters.  If $\delta(a)=1$, the proof doesn't require that I need to worry about $r\neq 0.$  Also, in light of exercise 29, it seems that it really doesn't matter.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "*If $\delta(a)=1$, the proof doesn't require that I need to worry about $r\neq 0.$*" Neither does it if $\delta=0$.

Comment: @Arthur, make your comment into an answer, so this question can be resolved.

Comment: For a field $R$, we can always take $r = 0$ in condition (ii), so the exact value of $\delta$ is irrelevant for Exercise 14. Similarly, if $\delta$ is constant, then the condition $\delta(r) < \delta(b)$ always fails, so it doesn't matter in Exercise 29 either whether you require $\delta > 0$ or just $\delta \geq 0$. (Condition (i) is easy to dispense with in both cases.)

Answer (score 9):

None of the requirements on $δ$ (apart from having a codomain of natural numbers) say anything about what values it actually takes, only whether it's larger or smaller on some points than on others. If $x↦δ(x)$ fulfills all the requirements, then so does $x↦δ(x)+1$. And if $δ(x)$ is never equal to $0$, so does $x↦δ(x)−1$ (and so does any other manipulation you can think of that preserves the order and doesn't take us out of the codomain of natural numbers).